# What is the meaning of some Tables in the Reporting database?

Tags: sql-database, reporting

I am working with `Sitecore` `Reporting Database` to analyze the website, but I don't know the purpose of each tables and their relationship.

It would be great help if someone share some documents around this.

If not, can someone explain the purpose of `dbo.Fact_PageViews`, `dbo.Fact_FormSummary` and `dbo.Contacts`

Comment: What Sitecore version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `reporting DB` has a table `Fact_PageViews`. The fact table is a data warehousing term used to describe tables that contain measurements and metrics. In a fact table, foreign keys allow join to be made with dimension tables. The `Fact_PageViews` table contains statistical data about online or offline contact interaction. The table structure looks like this.

[image]

Read more:
https://pushpaganan.home.blog/2022/06/05/sitecore-analytics-report-query/

`Fact_FormSummary` contains the summary for each field in different forms. For example, it has the following data

[image]

Read more:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-power-sitecore-wffm-through-sql-rohit-chopra

A `contact` represents an individual who interacts with or may potentially interact with your organization. `Contacts` are represented by the `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact` class, and are uniquely identified by `ID` (of type Guid) within the `xDB`. IDs are generated by the service layer when a contact is saved and should not be saved outside the xDB. `Contacts` also have one or more identifiers that identifies the contact to systems outside the `xDB`.

Read more: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/contacts.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it is very helpful and i can understand more from your information provided. Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

The `Reporting` database contains aggregated data from the `xDB.Collection` database. This statistical data generated by the aggregation pipeline and used by Sitecore Reporting applications is stored in `Fact` and `Dimension` tables.

The `Contacts` table contains information about contacts - individuals who interact with your Sitecore website.  The `Fact_PageViews` table contains statistical data about online and/or offline contact interactions.

I believe that you use the Web Forms For Marketers (WFFM) module as you have the `Fact_FormSummary` table in your Reporting DB. If so then this table was created by `[site root]\Website\Data\WFFM_Analytics.sql` script while installing the WFFM module and contains stats about online contact interactions with the WFFM forms.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thank you, @LâmMaiXuân, I am glad that my response helped you. If so, please accept my answer. Thanks.